# See what Azure Cloud Backup is actually backing up

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I have a client where I've recently implemented Azure Backup as their offsite backup solution. The server does about 400 MB of backups over the weekends, when there isn't anyone in the office.

Does anyone know if there's a way to look at what files are backed up by a particular Job in Azure Backup? The server is Windows Server Standard 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start playing with PowerShell to do this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh831765.aspx

The the following commands looks promising (I haven't used backup yet, so test and see the results your self)

- **Get-OBAllRecoveryPoints**: Gets all available recovery points. During recovery after the authentication process is complete, a list of recovery points for each successful backup that was completed from a specific server is shown to the user. The user can choose to restore date from within a specific recovery point.
- **Get-OBRecoverableSource**: Gets the list of data sources that are recoverable from this server or the specified OBBackupServer object. This list is used to get an item-level recovery.
- **Get-OBMachineUsage**: Gets the amount of storage that is consumed by the Microsoft Azure Backup as data that is backed up from this server. This would represent the data available across all recoverable points.